# View and update value from database in `<input>` using PHP

Tags: php

I have an update form that has three inputs. Now, I want to retrieve values from database in the inputs and update them after I click update and it works fine. But, the problem is that I must refresh after pressing the update button to see the changes (the automatic refresh and manual refresh). I need the value to change instantly after pressing the update button. How to do this? This is my code:

```
<?php
 require_once 'core/init.php';
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = '$customer_id'");
 while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $first_name = $res['first_name'];
  $last_name = $res['last_name'];
    $mobile_number = $res['mobile_number'];
}

if(isset($_POST['submit_0'])) {
  $first_Name = ((isset($_POST['First_Name']))?sanitize($_POST['First_Name']):'');
  $last_Name = ((isset($_POST['Last_Name']))?sanitize($_POST['Last_Name']):'');
  $db->query("UPDATE customers SET first_name = '{$first_Name}', last_Name = '{$last_Name}' WHERE id = '{$customer_id}'");
}
 ?>
<form action="personal_details.php" method="post" id="personal_details">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label for="First_Name" style="font-weight: bold; cursor:text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="First_Name" id="First_Name" class="form-control form-control-lg"
    value="<?=$first_name;?>" style="width:770px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-lg-12">
  <label for="Last_Name" style="font-weight: bold; cursor:text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" class="form-control form-control-lg"
  value="<?=$last_name;?>" style="width:770px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-lg-7">
  <label for="mobile_number" style="font-weight: bold;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Mobile Phone Number</label>
  <input type="tel" name="mobile_number" id="monu" class="form-control form-control-lg"
  value="<?=$mobile_number;?>" style="background-color:#EEEEEE; cursor:default;" readonly>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to make use of AJAX (JavaScript) in order to accomplish this without a page refresh.

Comment: Just move the update part before the select part. As it is now you're selecting the values you'll display before you do the update.

Comment: WOW!! That did the trick !! Thanks @Don'tPanic again :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: You may want to look into [PRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to prevent form resubmissions, and you should also read up on SQL injection. The way you're putting parameters into the queries right now isn't safe. Lots of good info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I noticed one more thing. In the navigation bar the name in Welcome, name doesn't change until I do a manual refresh as it was before. This is the part of the code of navigation bar of welcome. `<span><a style="margin-left:25px; color: #1C5D6B; text-decoration: none;"> Welcome, <?=$customer_data['first_name'];?>`. How to make this change instantly?

Comment: See [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496). Do not rely on sanitizers.

Comment: Please guys I need your help regarding this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014456/intl-tel-input-plugin-country-code-and-validation noone has answered me yet :(((